# Short bio for thesis back cover?

Tags: thesis

I thought about writing a short bio, maybe 100 words, for the back cover of my thesis.

Should I do this? What to include in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking of your thesis like a book, and indeed in some countries/disciplines, at least a few copies to get produced as such.

For most theses that I see these days, however, the notion of "back cover" is entirely meaningless.  There is an electronic document that starts with a cover page, which you might consider a "front cover" if you want to, but the end of the document has nothing in particular to distinguish it, except that you come to the end of the references and/or appendices.  Moreover, many institutions have fairly strong requirements for thesis formatting, and in most that I have encountered there is no place for an author bio.

As such, I think that adding an author bio would not make sense, unless it is specifically part of a format that you are required to use by your institution.

Comment: Is not a requirement. In fact, I think is not necessary. My CV is in LinkedIn.

Comment: For what it's worth, many universities require a vita page in thesis, which is essentially a bio.

Comment: On the other hand, if it's brief and accurate and modest it isn't likely to do any harm. (My usual response to web forms with a "bio" box is "Yes, mostly biological.")